# How can I access UIImage dark appearance pre iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, asset-catalog, ios-darkmode

I've just added dark mode to my app.

Asset catalogs support multiple appearances for each asset, on iOS 13 this means the correct asset is used when the system is running in dark or light mode.

[image: xcode image asset catalog appearances]
*These are not my real assets*

**I'm trying to support dark mode on older iOS versions.**
In my attempts to do so, I have added an override to force dark mode which works for my custom colours and theming but not for the images.

Is it possible to access the `dark` appearance of an image programatically before iOS13?

**For iOS12 I have tried using the following:**

```
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    let traits = UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark)
    let image = UIImage(
        named: "Image", 
        in: bundle, 
        compatibleWith: traits
    )
}
```

This only returns the normal appearance, and the method naming seems to suggest this only checks that the trait collection I've passed is compatible with the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to do that with just one asset. Below iOS 13 the system will always take the `Any` appearance. You would need to create two different image sets with different names and choose either one of them.

It is a bit confusing since `UIUserInterfaceStyle` is available in iOS 12+, but this is likely because macOS got Dark Mode that year.

Comment: I think you might be right, I've spent the best part of the afternoon trying various ways of accessing the `dark` variant, even the `UIImageAsset` can't get me there. sad times.

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunately not backward compatible. I'd recommend to use tintable images whenever possible since it's easier to change colors this way.

Comment: Thanks, yeah most of our icons are tin-table we just have a number graphics that are a little more involved. accepting this for now as seems like it's the only way to go.